# A quad Riley with 4 (little) parts

Tags: riddle, word

My prefix is a person, trust him you cannot.
My first infix is a number, must work with circles to find it.
My second infix is confirmative, when you understand what you were told.
My suffix is so cold.
But overall I'm just tasty for some.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Are you

> Spice?

My prefix is a person, trust him you cannot.

> Spi

My first infix is a number, must work with circles to find it.

> Pi

My second infix is confirmative, when you understand what you were told.

> From WEZL "i c(I see) what you are saying".

My suffix is so cold.

> Ice

But overall I'm just tasty for some.

> Spice

Comment: IC: "*I see* what you're saying"

Comment: That was quick, wow! I guess i have to be more vague with my hints :)

Comment: Nice Riddle @JakeOPJ :D